# Splitting Excel Cells Data

Tags: excel, parsing, mapping, cell, split

I have data like this:

```
0, no, Male
1, no, Female  
9, yes, Missing
```

in a single cell of excel.

The problem is to convert it to something like:

```
0   | no    | male  
1   | no    | female  
9   | yes   | missing
```

every value in three cells under heading `code | missing | description`

Text to rows conversion doesn't help and I can't do it manually as we have a large number of rows.

How to proceed?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Reformatted it. Is it decipherable now??

Comment: Much better!  You want to convert from one cell to nine cells??

Comment: Yes in three rows. Basically in the whole dataset I have many many cells like this and with more data point inside. I have to convert the whole file into the format I specified.

Comment: "Text to Columns" should work if you select a comma delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is all in one cell, you may need to get rid of the line breaks prior to using Text-To-Columns.

- Do a Find & Replace, and in the "Find" field hold down ALT and press 0010 (this won't really show up as any character in the field). Leave the replace field blank. This will find the line breaks and get rid of them, putting your cell contents in one line.
- Then, once your line breaks are gone you can simply use Text-To-Columns with Comma and Space as your delimiters.

**Edit:**

Or, you can just do it all in one step and include the `ALT+0010` as a delimiter in the "Other" field when you do Text-To-Columns.

**Second Edit:**

Alternatively, if you don't have much data you can Copy and Paste it into MS Word using "Keep Text Only". Then Find & Replace the quotation marks to get rid of them, and just Copy that back into Excel. Then do Text-to-Columns.

Comment: Thanks. Actually even I realized this solution myself, copied to notepad, copied to wordpad, got rid of quotation marks and every other blah blah. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select "Text to Columns" under the Data tab
2. Select "Delimited" and click next
3. Uncheck all boxes and only check "Comma"
4. Click Finish

[image: first]

[image: second]

Comment: doesn't work. It will only convert text to columns for the first two string/numbers separated by commas. What happens is the data is in three lines inside same cell. So, excel perceives it as `0, no,  male1, no, female9, yes, missing`.  Therefore the result is only 0 and no in two cells. That's it. I had tried it before asking.

Comment: Where did the data come from? Was it a text file?